# Kubernetes resolving backend IP

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

### [image]

My backend and frontend is deployed on Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE). And lets consider these steps -

1. User opens up browser and points to `yyy.yyy.yyy:8080`.
2. Browser loads the login page.
3. User enters username/password and presses "login" button.
4. Browser (ReactJS App) sends request to REST backend `xxx.xxx.xxx:7070` to do the validation.

Now my question is, how can we inject the backend (in this case `xxx.xxx.xxx`) ip frontend pod? Because this ip is not static (i dont want to make it static), and will be provided by GKE. I don't want to proxy my backend call through frontend either. Neither I want to use `nginx`, the reason is, one more POD, and config to maintain. Just don't want to have `nginx` for only this reason.

Should I create ingress? I mean something like-

```
`/`      <-- serves ReactJS app

`/api`   <--- serves REST api
```

Or there is a way to inject the ip of backend POD?

What is the best approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use fully qualified domain name instead of static IP. 
What about a nginx reverse proxy to send the request to backend APIs?

Comment: On AWS there's a Kubernetes Service annotation to allocate a DNS name (via Route 53) and attach it to the load balancer.  I'm having trouble finding something equivalent for GCP, but that's the core of the right answer.

Comment: @ImtiazMirza: In kubernetes there is no FQDN. POD IP is dynamic. Only possible way is Service (I mean LoadBalancer), which again is not static anyway.

I thought about nginx before making this post. But the problem is, nginx means one more POD to deploy, maintain, and configs maintenance. So I am sort of looking for within kubernetes solutions (as I mentioned, maybe Ingress)

Comment: @DavidMaze I am on GCE, also my DNS is not registered with GCE. My DNS is registered with some local IPS

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the pods directly from the outside. The only way in is through a service of type `LoadBalancer`. External IP you get for such a service is static for GKE (AWS gives a DNS name instead)

For every service of type `LoadBalancer` the cloud provider will spin up a load balancer that you have to pay for. You can funnel all http traffic through a single ingress service that would fan out your requests based on host DNS or URI path and other options. Which is what pretty much everyone does. If you want to setup something like that google for ingress

Comment: Please check my question and the diagram I have provided. I already know who LoadBalancers works, and I am already using it.

Comment: Your diagram is wrong as I see it. The load balancers are outside of kubernetes.  The fact that GKE spins them up for you based on what you put down in a service descriptor doesn't matter. If you know how it works you should know that the IP addresses are static. If you insist on having your diagram sans moving the load balancers outside of GKE box, you should buy DNS entries for each of the services and bind them to the IPs you receive from Google for those services and tell your app to use these DNS for these services (this last part applies even if you use an ingress)

Comment: I don't think my diagram is wrong. I am not sure if about your comment of load balancer is outside of kubernetes. At least the kubernetes spec includes load balancer (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/). Yes, on a cloud environment the load balancer is configured as provided package, but still that provided package follows Kubernetes load balancer spec. 

Now about buying DNS entries, as I mentioned before on one of the comment, I already have DNS service from one the service provider.

Comment: I would suggest using either type:Loadbalancer, as @LevKuznetsov mentioned or an Ingress. If you use the "LoadBalancer" type, this will create a Network Load Balancer within Google Cloud Networking. If you use an Ingress, then this will create an HTTP/S Load Balancer within Google Cloud Networking. Here is an article that explains the pros and cons for each method I have mentioned (https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-nodeport-vs-loadbalancer-vs-ingress-when-should-i-use-what-922f010849e0). You can choose which method fits your use case.